# How do I get the Channel for an extension in Asterisk VOIP?

Tags: asterisk

If I know the user's extension, how do I translate that into a channel so that I can make a call on their behalf?

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

Comment: You would need to clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve here? Are you transferring a call are just initiating a new one? Why not just dial rthe extension and set your user Caller ID before hand?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `CoreShowChannels` is the one you want:

```
asterisk*CLI> manager show command CoreShowChannels 
[Syntax]
Action: CoreShowChannels
[ActionID:] <value>

[Synopsis]
List currently active channels. 

[Description]
List currently defined channels and some information about them.

[Arguments]
ActionID
    ActionID for this transaction. Will be returned.

[See Also]
Not available
```

Comment: Nothing. It says it completely successfully but with 0 records.

Comment: Sounds like there are no channels :)